# Add fields to Javascript/PHP form WORDPRESS

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms

I am struggling to add additional fields to a Javascript form. Can you let me know if I'm missing something obvious?

The new fields are the phone number "edgtf_enquiry_number" and ceremony date "edgtf_enquiry_ceremony_date".

I have added them to all the relevant files, but it says the input does not exist when tested.

Enquiry Form

```
<?php

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

?>
<div class="edgtf-enquiry-holder">
    <div class="edgtf-enquiry-inner">
        <a class="edgtf-enquiry-close" href="#">
            <?php echo urbango_edge_icon_collections()->renderIcon( 'icon_close', 'font_elegant' ); ?>
        </a>
        <form class="edgtf-enquiry-form" method="POST">
            <h5 class="edgtf-enquiry-title">
                <span class="edgtf-enquiry-title-label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Contact', 'urbango-listing' ); ?></span>
            </h5>
            <input type="text" name="edgtf_enquiry_name" id="edgtf-enquiry-name" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Your Full Name*', 'urbango-listing' ); ?>" required pattern=".{6,}"/>
            <input type="email" name="edgtf_enquiry_email" id="edgtf-enquiry-email" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Your E-mail*', 'urbango-listing' ); ?>" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"/>
            <input type="text" name="edgtf_enquiry_number" id="edgtf-enquiry-number" value="Phone Number" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Your Phone Number', 'urbango-listing' ); ?>" required/>
            <input type="date" name="edgtf_enquiry_ceremony_date" id="edgtf-enquiry-ceremony-date" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Ceremony Date (if known)', 'urbango-listing' ); ?>"/>
            <textarea name="edgtf_enquiry_message" id="edgtf-enquiry-message" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Your Message*', 'urbango-listing' ); ?>" required></textarea>
            <div class="eqf-privacy-statement">By filling out this form you are agreeing to outdoorceremonies.co.uk passing your information on to this supplier so that they may respond to you directly. Your data will be stored in line with our <a href="/privacy-policy">privacy policy.</a></div>

            <?php if ( urbango_listing_is_core_plugin_installed() ) {
                echo urbango_edge_get_button_html( array(
                    'custom_class' => 'edgtf-enquiry-submit',
                    'html_type'    => 'button',
                    'text'         => esc_html__( 'Send Your Message', 'urbango-listing' )
                ) );
            } ?>

            <input type="hidden" id="edgtf-enquiry-item-id" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'urbango_listing_validate_listing_item_enquiry_form', 'urbango_listing_nonce_listing_item_enquiry_form' ); ?>
        </form>
        <div class="edgtf-enquiry-response"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    var enquiry = {};
    edgtf.modules.enquiry = enquiry;

    enquiry.edgtfOnDocumentReady = edgtfOnDocumentReady;

    $(document).ready(edgtfOnDocumentReady);

    /*
     All functions to be called on $(document).ready() should be in this function
     */
    function edgtfOnDocumentReady() {
        edgtfInitEnquiryForm();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes enquiry form
     */
    function edgtfInitEnquiryForm() {
        var singleHolder = $('.edgtf-listing-single-holder'),
            enquiryHolder = $('.edgtf-enquiry-holder');

        if (enquiryHolder.length) {
            var openerButton = singleHolder.find('.edgtf-enquiry-opener'),
                enquiryForm = enquiryHolder.find('.edgtf-enquiry-form'),
                enquiryFormCloseButton = enquiryHolder.find('.edgtf-enquiry-close'),
                responseMessage = enquiryHolder.find('.edgtf-enquiry-response');

            openerButton.on('click', function () {
                enquiryHolder.fadeIn(300).addClass('edgtf-opened');
            });

            enquiryFormCloseButton.on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                enquiryHolder.fadeOut(300).removeClass('edgtf-opened');
            });

            // Close form on esc key
            $(window).on('keyup', function (e) {
                if (enquiryHolder.hasClass('edgtf-opened') && e.keyCode === 27) {
                    enquiryHolder.fadeOut(300).removeClass('edgtf-opened');
                }
            });

            enquiryForm.on('submit', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                responseMessage.empty().html('<span class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></span>');

                var enquiryData = {
                    name: enquiryForm.find('#edgtf-enquiry-name').val(),
                    email: enquiryForm.find('#edgtf-enquiry-email').val(),
                    message: enquiryForm.find('#edgtf-enquiry-message').val(),
                    itemID: enquiryForm.find('#edgtf-enquiry-item-id').val(),
                    nonce: enquiryForm.find('#urbango_listing_nonce_listing_item_enquiry_form').val(),
                    number: enquiryForm.find('#edgtf-enquiry-number').val(),
                    date: enquiryForm.find('#edgtf_enquiry_ceremony_date').val()
                };


                var requestData = {
                    action: 'urbango_listing_send_listing_item_enquiry',
                    enquiryData: enquiryData,

                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: edgtfGlobalVars.vars.edgtfAjaxUrl,
                    data: requestData,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var response = JSON.parse(data);

                        if (response.status === 'success') {
                            responseMessage.html(response.message);

                            setTimeout(function () {
                                enquiryHolder.fadeOut(300).removeClass('edgtf-opened');
                            }, 800);
                        } else {
                            responseMessage.html(response.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Email Helper Functions

```
<?php

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

if ( ! function_exists( 'urbango_listing_get_listing_item_enquiry_form' ) ) {
    function urbango_listing_get_listing_item_enquiry_form() {
        $allowed_pages = apply_filters( 'urbango_listing_filter_allowed_enquiry_pages', array() );

        if ( ! empty( $allowed_pages ) && get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'edgtf_listing_enable_enquiry_form_meta', true ) === 'yes' ) {
            foreach ( $allowed_pages as $allowed_page ) {
                if ( is_singular( $allowed_page ) ) {
                    urbango_listing_get_module_template_part( 'modules', 'enquiry', 'templates/enquiry-form' );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    add_action( 'urbango_edge_action_before_page_header', 'urbango_listing_get_listing_item_enquiry_form' );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'urbango_listing_send_listing_item_enquiry' ) ) {
    function urbango_listing_send_listing_item_enquiry() {

        if ( isset( $_POST['enquiryData'] ) ) {
            $error           = false;
            $responseMessage = '';
            $email_data = $_POST['enquiryData'];
            $nonce      = $email_data['nonce'];


            if ( wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'urbango_listing_validate_listing_item_enquiry_form' ) ) {

                // Validate input fields
                if ( ! empty( $email_data['name'] ) ) {
                    $name = esc_attr( esc_html( $email_data['name'] ) );
                } else {
                    $error           = true;
                    $responseMessage = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid name.', 'urbango-listing' );
                }


                if ( ! empty( $email_data['email'] ) ) {
                    $email = sanitize_email( $email_data['email'] );
                } else {
                    $error           = true;
                    $responseMessage = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid email.', 'urbango-listing' );
                }

                if ( ! empty( $email_data['number'] ) ) {
                    $name = esc_attr( esc_html( $email_data['number'] ) );
                } else {
                    $error           = true;
                    $responseMessage = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid number.', 'urbango-listing' );
                }

                if ( ! empty( $email_data['date'] ) ) {
                    $name = esc_attr( esc_html( $email_data['date'] ) );
                } else {
                    $error           = true;
                    $responseMessage = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid date.', 'urbango-listing' );
                }



                if ( ! empty( $email_data['message'] ) ) {
                    $message = esc_attr( esc_html( $email_data['message'] ) );
                } else {
                    $error           = true;
                    $responseMessage = esc_html__( 'Please enter a valid message.', 'urbango-listing' );
                }

                // Send mail and response
                if ( $error ) {
                    urbango_listing_get_ajax_status( 'error', $responseMessage );
                } else {
                    // Get post id from request
                    $post_id = $email_data['itemID'];


                    // Get email address from single page meta option
                    $mail_to = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'edgtf_listing_single_contact_email_meta', true );

                    $headers = array(
                        'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>',
                        'Reply-To: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>',
                        'Bcc: Outdoor Ceremonies <hello@lydiarosedesign.co.uk>',
                    );

                    $messageTemplate = esc_html__( 'From', 'urbango-listing' ) . ': ' . $name . "\r\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__( 'Email', 'urbango-listing' ) . ': ' . $email . "\r\n\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__( 'Phone Number', 'urbango-listing' ) . ': ' . $number . "\r\n\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__( 'Ceremony Date', 'urbango-listing' ) . ': ' . $date . "\r\n\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__( 'Message', 'urbango-listing' ) . ': ' . $message . "\r\n\n";
                    $messageTemplate .= esc_html__( 'Message sent via enquiry form on', 'urbango-listing' ) . ' ' . esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) . ' - ' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );

                    wp_mail(
                        sanitize_email( $mail_to ), // Mail To
                        sprintf( esc_html__( 'New Enquiry From %s', 'urbango-listing' ), $name ), // Subject
                        $messageTemplate, // Message
                        $headers // Additional Headers
                    );

                    urbango_listing_get_ajax_status( 'success', esc_html__( 'Enquiry is successfully sent.', 'urbango-listing' ) );

                    unset( $_POST['enquiryData'] ); // Remove data from global post variable after submission
                }
            } else {
                urbango_listing_get_ajax_status( 'error', esc_html__( 'Nonce is invalid.', 'urbango-listing' ) );
            }
        } else {
            urbango_listing_get_ajax_status( 'error', esc_html__( 'Please review your enquiry and send again.', 'urbango-listing' ) );
        }
    }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_urbango_listing_send_listing_item_enquiry', 'urbango_listing_send_listing_item_enquiry' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_urbango_listing_send_listing_item_enquiry', 'urbango_listing_send_listing_item_enquiry' );
}
```

Comment: Who says that the input doesn't exist? Is there a specific plugin that you are working with?

Comment: I get the error message in the form and it won't submit. I've added a screenshot. 
It's part of the theme Urbango by Qode.

[Screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/JYdi9Aw.png)